# JSON RPC Application: Adding Byte Array to JToken

Tags: java, json, vb.net, json.net

I've spent a few hours searching the forum for an answer to this question before posting this, so please excuse me if somewhere the question has been asked.

I need to send a 2-byte parameter via Jason RPC, but I'm having some difficulty.

I'm using VB.NET (VS 2013) as my development platform. I've created a send function that is the source of my problem. Here is a snippet:

```
    **Public Function daliSend(url As String, universe_id As Integer, bytes As Byte(), expect_answer As Boolean, send_twice As Boolean) As Result
        Dim rpcObject As New JObject() From { _
            {"Id", generateRandomString()}, _
            {"Jsonrpc", "2.0"}, _
            {"method", "dali.send"}, _
            {"params", New JObject() From { _
                {"universe_id", universe_id}, _
                {"bytes", bytes}, _
                {"expect_answer", expect_answer}, _
                {"send_twice", send_twice} _
            }} _
        }
      Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rpcObject ).ToLower()**
```

I'm sending "bytes" as a byte array [187,0] (i.e bytes(0) = 187, bytes(1) = 0) for my RPC Request. However, the Jtoken immediately converts the byte array to a string via base 64 encoding.

Using TextVisualizer, I see that rpcObject  =

**{
  "Id": "penultes",
  "Jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "dali.send",
  "params": {
    "universe_id": 4,
    "bytes": "uwA=",
    "expect_answer": true,
    "send_twice": false
  }
}**

By definition in the Json.Net Serialization Guide, Primitive Type Byte[] converts to String (base 64 encoded). Essentially, the following .NET conversion is occurring Convert.ToBase64String(bytes), which produces the string "uwA=".

I can live with that. However, this needs to be changed BEFORE serialization to a string. Any ideas on how I can modify the above object (rpcObject) prior to serialization? What I need to do is convert the string parameter "bytes" value "uwA=" back to "[187,0]" possibly using Convert.FromBase64String(), so an array is serialized versus a string.

I haven't found an easy way to isolate just that parameter before serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Json.NET will only serialize a byte **array** as Base64.  Other non-array byte collections will be serialized as integer arrays, e.g. the collection returned by [`Array.AsReadOnly<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53kysx7b(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim rpcObject As New JObject() From { _
    {"Id", generateRandomString()}, _
    {"Jsonrpc", "2.0"}, _
    {"method", "dali.send"}, _
    {"params", New JObject() From { _
        {"universe_id", universe_id}, _
            {"bytes", JToken.FromObject(Array.AsReadOnly(bytes))}, _
        {"expect_answer", expect_answer}, _
        {"send_twice", send_twice} _
    }} _
}
```

Here I am using [`JToken.FromObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm) to serialize the read-only collection wrapper to the required intermediate [`JArray`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm).  You could also serialize any other similarly equivalent byte collection, e.g. `bytes.ToList()`.  However `Array.AsReadOnly<T>()` returns a read only collection *wrapper* and thus should consume minimal memory for large input byte arrays.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ch6qru).

Comment: Great! I'll give that a try.

Comment: What ended up working was changing the byte array to a list (i.e. bytes as List(Of [Byte])